# how to use code igniter email in a contact page (core php) called as a wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

how to use code igniter email in a contact page (core php) called as a wordpress page. i can make it wordpress free & stand alone php file if its required.the problem with core php mail is it sends all the mails right into the junk/spam folder.

```
if(!$error)



 {
    //trim($_POST[your_name])." sent you a message from ".get_option("blogname")." website "." on subject "


    $headers = "From: ".trim($_POST[your_name])." <".trim($_POST[your_email]).">\r\nReply-To:".trim($_POST[your_email])."\r\n" ;

    $headers .=  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

    $headers .=  'mailed-by: hisham@rainhopes.com' . "\r\n";

    $headers .= "X-Priority: 2\nX-MSmail-Priority: high";

  //$headers .= 'From: abc@yahoo.com' . "\r\n";


     $email = mail(get_option("admin_email"),trim($_POST[your_subject]),stripslashes(trim($_POST[your_message])),$headers);
}


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

mail() function does not provide any assistance for making use of popular features such as HTML-based emails and attachments into the mailbox.

I suggest the [PHPMailer librairy](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), the most robust and pupular php mail library.

*EDIT* this code should do the job

```
if(!$error){
    require 'path/to/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->setFrom(trim($_POST[your_name]));   
    $mail->addReplyTo(trim($_POST[your_email]));
    $mail->addAddress(get_option("admin_email"));  
    $mail->addCC(get_option("admin2_email_something"));

    $mail->isHTML(true);   // Set email format to  HTML

    $mail->Subject = trim($_POST[your_subject]);
    $mail->Body    = stripslashes(trim($_POST[your_message]));

    if(!$mail->send()) {
         echo 'Message could not be sent.';
         echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that i have to use it on a wordpress project.

Comment: this thing is causing all the trouble .. mailed-by: admiral.websitewelcome.com  it cannot be changed via headers...                        Why is this message in Spam? We've found that lots of messages from admiral.websitewelcome.com are spam.

Answer (score 0):

fixed all the trouble.. just put this one after the header parameter..

```
$email = mail(get_option("admin_email"),trim($_POST[your_subject]),stripslashes(trim($_POST[your_message])),$headers, "-fsender@domain.com");
```